# Download youtube playlist from youtube-dl. but no sounds

Tags: sound, youtube-dl

i am downloaused from youtube playlist used from youtube-dl. no sounds in that mp4 files.

```
youtube-dl -f 136 --write-auto-sub --convert-subs srt https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLgyc****
```

i am try to download 720p mp4 file with srt subtitle file.
not convert to vtt to srt.
please help

Comment: Does this option require FFmpeg installed? Can you give the playlist URL for testing?

Comment: yes.i installed FFmpeg.  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD20298E653A970F8

Comment: I am sloved the problem. video format 136 is a video only. format no 22 is a best video 720p  with audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video format 136 is a video only. Video format 22 is 720p video with audio.